# Best practice for creation scheduled methods in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

What is best way for schedulers creations from next(or your variant):

1) For one scheduled  method create one component and call service from this mrthod:

```
@Component
public class MyScheduler {

    private final MyService myService;

    public MyScheduler(MyService myService) {
        this.myService= myService;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1L)
    public void process() {
     myService.startSomethig();
    }
}
```

2) Create one component for all scheduled methods and start service for concrete method:

```
@Component
public class MySchedulers {

    private final MyService1 myService1;
    private final MyService2 myService2;
    private final MyService3 myService3;

    public MySchedulers (MyService1 myService1, MyService2 myService2, MyService3 myService3) {
        this.myService1 = myService1;
        this.myService2 = myService2;
        this.myService3 = myService3;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 100L)
    public void process() {
     myService1.startSomethig();
    }

     @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 666L)
    public void process() {
     myService2.startAny();
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 999L)
    public void process() {
     myService3.startAll();
    }
}
```

3) Create cheduled method in each concreate service:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

     //filds, constructor

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 100L)
    public void process() {
       startSomethig();
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void startSomethig() {
        //...
    }
```

Which approach is better? maybe there are others? I will be glad to hear your opinion

Answer (score 4):

There is no best way, it all "depends".

1). This is close to what I usually do - I create a class with name ending with "Job", like "GenerateReportJob" that has scheduled method that often just calls another service class.

2). If you have scheduled jobs that use same dependencies and it's purpose is related to each other - nothing wrong with putting them to the same class. But you should avoid creating just single class for all possible scheduled jobs there are in your application - it will quickly become huge file with lots of dependencies hard to reason about.

3). I avoid putting `@Scheduled` directly on service methods as I find it hard to locate all the jobs in the application. Technically it works, but it's not developer friendly in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer and have implemented the second method for my project.

The main reason for choosing this way is **centralized control** over all periodic tasks. The scheduled tasks in my project have intensive database usage and in this way, I can prevent overlaps on running jobs.

The second reason is the **readability of code**. It is easier for co-developers to find newly added scheduled tasks.

Finally, I agree with Maciej. The best model for you depends on your tasks and your point of view to create a good structure for your own project.